# Read back string from a function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a quick function to generate a random string

```
.h

@interface ICObjects : NSObject

+(void)certRef:(NSString *)randomCertRef;
```

---

```
.m
@implementation ICObjects



+(void)certRef:(NSString *)randomCertRef{

    NSLog(@"REF PRESSED");
    NSInteger rNumber = arc4random() % 100000000 + 1;
    randomCertRef = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"V/R %d", rNumber];
    NSLog(@"REF RESULT %@",randomCertRef);


}
```

Reading it back in my view seems to be eluding me

`self.mytextString = [ICObjects certRef.text];`  ("expected" ])

`self.mytextString = [[ICObjects certRef ]text];` ("No known class method" ])

Comment: Do you want a class method that will return you an NSString* (certRef) ? Your function takes a parameter (randomCertRef) but does not use it (it gets overwritten). Do you really need it ?

Comment: I erroneously posted this as an answer. Leave alone the question, the compiler complained about how you invoke a class method. In case you really needed a parameter, the correct syntax would have been `self.mytextString = [ICObjects certRef:text];` but with a `NSString *` return type for `certRef:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your function does not use the parameter `randomCertRef` since you overwrite it. So my guess is you want something like this :

```
+(NSString*)certRef
{
    NSLog(@"REF PRESSED");
    NSInteger rNumber = arc4random() % 100000000 + 1;
    NSString *randomCertRef = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"V/R %d", rNumber];
    NSLog(@"REF RESULT %@",randomCertRef);

    return randomCertRef;
}
```

to be used like this :

```
   self.mytextString = [ICObjects certRef];
```

Comment: Thank you Jean thats sorted it